# Solve JAXB "name collision in the ObjectFactory class" problem with customisation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Executing a "xjc" command on [these xsd files](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/) returns a `Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class` because there are 2 elements named "Scale" and "scale".

According to [this page](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_errors.html#Two_declarations_cause_a_collision_in_the_ObjectFactory_class), this problem may be solved by customizing the xsd files with `<factoryMethod>`.

Do you know how to do that? Do you have an example of binding file to do that?

Comment: Excellent answer there: http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2008/10/17/generating-kml-restful-clients

Comment: Link above does not currently resolve.  Wayback Machine version is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20090221124958/http://lunatech-research.com/archives/2008/10/17/kml-restful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the bindings tag. Set the schemaLocation attribute to the location of a particular xsd. The child tags, schemaBindings and package, then define a new package namespace for that xsd. Below is the bindings file I used with xjc a while ago. If it still works, great. If not, example =).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1"
      xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
      xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

  <bindings schemaLocation="ogckml22.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="net.opengis.kml"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="kml22gx.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="net.opengis.kml.ex"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="atom-author-link.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="org.w3c.atom"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="xAL.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="org.oasis.xal"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="kml:scale">
    <class name="scaleliteral"/>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="kml:snippet">
    <class name="snippetliteral"/>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="kml:Snippet">
    <property name="snippetDeprecated"/>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="atom:link">
    <property name="atomLink"/>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have solved the problem now. This page has also been usefull: http://acuriousanimal.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-jaxb-to-generate-kml-java-classes.html

Answer (score 6):

Did you try `-B-XautoNameResolution` ? It might not always do the trick but best to give a try before writing a binding file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. -B-XautoNameResolution is unfortunately not a recognized xjc parameter. I am using version 2.1.10.

Comment: its called `-XautoNameResolution` in 2.1.10 - I had the same problem. It works as wanted if you leave the `-B`

Comment: where did you find this out? Been looking for it, nothing in the docs

Answer (score 3):

One solution to your problem is to use the -p option to specify separate package names for each xsd file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a long try, following configuration worked for me. I am using jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3.1 and a separate binding file:

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.1</target>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <xjbSources>
                    <xjbSource>src/main/xjb/bindings-1.3.xjb</xjbSource>
                </xjbSources>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-Xfluent-api</argument>
                </arguments>
                <!-- Package name of the generated sources. -->
                <!-- Don't use it, because we've already declared separate package name inside bindings -->
                <!-- <packageName>com.abc.xyz.generated</packageName> -->
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/classes</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <extension>true</extension>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**bindings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/ccv1p3_imscp_v1p2_v1p0.xsd"
    node="//xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:serializable uid="1" />
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.abc.xyz.generated.manifest" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/profile/cc/ccv1p3/LOM/ccv1p3_lommanifest_v1p0.xsd"
    node="//xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.abc.xyz.generated.lommanifest" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/profile/cc/ccv1p3/LOM/ccv1p3_lomresource_v1p0.xsd"
    node="//xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.lcs.thincc.generated.lomresource" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Please note, that we don't need to specify `packageName` inside `pom.xml` instead we can declare it using `<jxb:schemaBindings>` inside **bindings.xjb** file which is much easier as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html).